# When executing pd.cocat, final data have NaN

Tags: pandas

When I use pd.concat, I encounter the specefic columns filled with NaN.

```
df_train_extended.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7339 entries, 0 to 7338
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------              --------------  ----- 
 0   sentence_id         7339 non-null   int64 
 1   person              7339 non-null   object
 2   sentence            7339 non-null   object
 3   scene               7339 non-null   object
 4   context             7339 non-null   object
 5   target_speaker_ctx  7339 non-null   object
 6   other_speaker_ctx   7339 non-null   object
 7   scene_sents         7339 non-null   object
dtypes: int64(1), object(7)
memory usage: 458.8+ KB

df_train_extended_augmented.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7339 entries, 0 to 7338
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------              --------------  ----- 
 0   sentence_id         7339 non-null   int64 
 1   person              7339 non-null   object
 2   sentence            7339 non-null   object
 3   scene               7339 non-null   object
 4   context             7339 non-null   object
 5   target_speaker_ctx  7339 non-null   object
 6   other_speaker_ctx   7339 non-null   object
 7   scene_sents         7339 non-null   object
dtypes: int64(1), object(7)
memory usage: 458.8+ KB
```

above tow dataframe have the name of sample column with Non-Null.
But the result of the pd.concat is below.

```
df_data = pd.concat([df_train_extended, df_train_data_augmented], axis=0, ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)
df_data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 14678 entries, 0 to 14677
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------              --------------  ----- 
 0   sentence_id         14678 non-null  int64 
 1   person              14678 non-null  object
 2   sentence            14678 non-null  object
 3   scene               14678 non-null  object
 4   context             14678 non-null  object
 5   target_speaker_ctx  7339 non-null   object
 6   other_speaker_ctx   7339 non-null   object
 7   scene_sents         7339 non-null   object
dtypes: int64(1), object(7)
memory usage: 917.5+ KB
```

I dont'n know why target_speaker_ctx, other_speaker_ctx, scene_sents of the df_data has NaN values.